# Launcher doesn't show open apps, 17.04

Tags: unity, launcher, 17.04

I've got open chrome and nautilus, but the launcher shows like there's nothing open. There're also a lot of bugs with the windows. Update: I found the problem, is a bamf2-index bad syntax
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDVUE.png)

Comment: What's the question? I'm sure there is a lot of bugs in the new release.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so it can help others with similar issues...

Comment: There's no a solution, is a bad line that i add to a file